# spring-integration SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am working with the SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway, currently I have the gateway putting the requests onto a channel then a flow consuming from the channel.   Everything seems to work great.

My question is, if you have multiple distinct soap endpoint services that each operate slightly differently how do I map these endpoints to different flows, what is the right way to do this?   Is it expected that you have a new SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway per soap web service endpoint and use the EndpointMapper to map to each one?   Or is there a better practice for doing this?  I wasn't quite sure if it was expected to have multiple Soap Gateways.

Also, any simple way to get access to the URI/URL that was used to make the ws call in the flow?  I noticed it doesn't seem to be in the headers.

Here is my sample configuration:

```
/**
 * URL mappings used by WS endpoints
 */
public static final String[] WS_URL_MAPPINGS = {"/services/*", "*.wsdl", "*.xsd"};
public static final String GATEWAY_INBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME  = "wsGatewayInboundChannel";
public static final String GATEWAY_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME = "wsGatewayOutboundChannel";


/**
 * Register the servlet mapper, note that it uses MessageDispatcher
 */
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    servlet.setTransformSchemaLocations(true);
    servlet.setPublishEvents(true);
    ServletRegistrationBean servletDef = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, WS_URL_MAPPINGS);
    servletDef.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return servletDef;
}

/**
 * Create a new Direct channels to handle the messages
 */
@Bean
public MessageChannel wsGatewayInboundChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct(GATEWAY_INBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME).get();
}
@Bean
public MessageChannel wsGatewayOutboundChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct(GATEWAY_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL_NAME).get();
}

/**
 * Startup the WebServiceInboundGateway Endpoint, this will handle the incoming SOAP requests
 *  and place them onto the request channel
 */
@Bean
public SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway webServiceInboundGateway(
        @Value("${spring.ws.should.track:true}") boolean shouldTrack
) {
    SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway wsg = new SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway();
    wsg.setRequestChannel(wsGatewayInboundChannel());
    wsg.setReplyChannel(wsGatewayOutboundChannel());
    wsg.setExtractPayload(false);  // Send the full RAW SOAPMessage and not just payload
    wsg.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    wsg.setShouldTrack(shouldTrack);
    wsg.setCountsEnabled(true);
    return wsg;
}


/**
 * Map the allowable service Uri's.
 *
 * although this isn't needed (can map everything using the mapping.setDefaultEndpoint)
 *  using this approach ensures that people don't use unexpected uris, probably can
 *  find a better way to deal with this in the future
 */
@Bean
public EndpointMapping uriEndpointMapping(@Qualifier("serviceUris") List<String> serviceUris
        , PayloadValidatingInterceptor payloadValidatingInterceptor
        , SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway webServiceInboundGateway) {
    UriEndpointMapping mapping = new UriEndpointMapping();
    mapping.setUsePath(true);
    Map<String, Object> endpointMap = new HashMap<>();
    endpointMap.put("/services/myservice1", webServiceInboundGateway);

    mapping.setEndpointMap(endpointMap);
    //mapping.setDefaultEndpoint(webServiceInboundGateway());

    return mapping;
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow itemLookupFlow(ItemLookupRequestToItemDetailsRequestTransformer requestTransformer
        , ItemDetailsResponseToItemLookupResponseTransformer responseTransformer) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("wsGatewayInboundChannel")
            .transform(new MyTransformer())
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
            .handle(myBean, "execute")
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Or is there a better practice for doing this?

Why does everybody treat Spring Integration as bad practice? Imaging the situation you don’t use Spring Integration in your application and only Spring WS.
So, now you need to write several endpoints. What you do? Right, develop several classes with the `@Endpoint` and/or appropriate url mapping. And somehow here you don’t say that it is bad practice and just follow the Framework requirements.

So, why by your opinion the distinct `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway`s is bad way to go?

I think different endpoints really means fully non-related logic, different transformation, routing and , finally, SOAP unmarshalling.

Therefore, consider a new `SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway` together with its downstream flow as a separate Spring WS `@Endpoint` class.

To get an URL you should inject a custom `SoapHeaderMapper`. I think `SoapMessage` has some hook to extract that info.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Artem, i was mainly just confirming that it was the right way to go.  There seem to be limited examples so i wanted to see what others were doing.

Comment: @artem_bilan I was going to ask same question, not because I think spring integration is bad practice. It is quite a good and mature frame work for integration. Just as limited samples are around web, I wanted to ask question to get some confirmation and  make sure I am on correct path. Good luck :)